# Make Emojis bigger in text?

Tags: flutter

Any idea how to make only the fontsize of emojis larger in the Text() widget?

The issue is that the Text() widget parses the emojis automatically. Sure, I can increase the overall text size, but I want the text to stay at the same fontsize.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this

Answer (score 6):

If you want to auto increase size of emojis in chat message you can use this method:

```
  static final RegExp REGEX_EMOJI = RegExp(
      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])');

  Widget _buildContent(String content) {
    final Iterable<Match> matches = REGEX_EMOJI.allMatches(content);
    if (matches.isEmpty)
      return Text(
        '${content}',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      );
    
    return RichText(
        text: TextSpan(children: [
      for (var t in content.characters)
        TextSpan(
            text: t,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: REGEX_EMOJI.allMatches(t).isNotEmpty ? 20.0 : 12.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            )),
    ]));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the widget `RichText`

```
RichText(
     text: TextSpan(
          text: 'hello',
          children: <TextSpan>[
             TextSpan(text: '', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))
          ]
     ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to apply this for a chat application (unknown user input) via a textcontroller?

Comment: Use case: Display the text provided by the user to the screen with larger emoji size?? @user3532201

Comment: Yes - consider a chat like this one: https://github.com/flutter/friendlychat-steps/blob/master/offline_steps/step_3_displaying_messages/lib/main.dart where _textController.text is used. I need to make only the emojis larger within the controller.

Comment: That you need to handle inside the itemBuilder. `itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index]`

Comment: I just don‘t know how to do it. The text is written by users, so I cannot just format it (it’s a chat). So a user writes ‘Hi ’, all emojis should automatically be increased by e.g. x3 (but not the text). How do I do it - maybe read the unicode? Moreover, I observed that Emojis on iOS are larger then the text, so the Textinputfield increases when somebody writes. Any idea on that?

Comment: @user3532201 I facing same isssue. did found a solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and find beginning of solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011139/change-emoji-font-for-flutter-in-android)
I've modified the code a little to allow showing text and emoji with different font size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Widget to render emoji and text with different font size
class EmojisText extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmojisText({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.color,
    required this.emojiSize,
    required this.textSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  ///The text which emoji and alpha-numeric characters
  ///emoji can be absent
  final String text;
  /// THe font size to set to emoji
  final double emojiSize;
  /// The font size to set to text
  final double textSize;
  /// the color of the text
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: _buildText(),
    );
  }

  TextSpan _buildText() {
    final children = <TextSpan>[];
    final runes = text.runes;

    for (int i = 0; i < runes.length; /* empty */) {
      int current = runes.elementAt(i);

      // we assume that everything that is not
      // in Extended-ASCII set is an emoji...
      final isEmoji = current > 255;
      final shouldBreak = isEmoji ? (x) => x <= 255 : (x) => x > 255;

      final chunk = <int>[];
      while (!shouldBreak(current)) {
        chunk.add(current);
        if (++i >= runes.length) break;
        current = runes.elementAt(i);
      }

      children.add(
        TextSpan(
          text: String.fromCharCodes(chunk),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: isEmoji ? emojiSize : textSize,
            color: color,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return TextSpan(children: children);
  }
}
```

Comment: // we assume that everything that is not
      // in Extended-ASCII set is an emoji...
this will mean most non English texts will take the size of the emoji not the normal text