# Change emoji Font for Flutter in Android

Tags: flutter, fonts, emoji

Android has horrid emojis. Can I use Apple's emoji font (like Telegram does and WhatsApp used to) in Flutter for Android?

Edit: My first guess would be to add a font, but as I do not want to change all other fonts I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: have you found a way yet ? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to define a custom font in Flutter **just for emojis** (or just for specified characters). There's an [open Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/84631) about this.

There is however a trick to mix your font and another one for your emojis in a Text widget. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter) to do that.

**Here are the steps you can follow :**

1. You need to choose the emoji font you want to use. My favorite one is this Joypixels :
   https://www.joypixels.com/fonts
2. Download the font .ttf and add it to your project, following the documentation :
   https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts
3. Add this code to your project :

```
class TextWithEmojis extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWithEmojis({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.fontSize,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final double fontSize;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: _buildText(),
    );
  }

  TextSpan _buildText() {
    final children = <TextSpan>[];
    final runes = text.runes;

    for (int i = 0; i < runes.length; /* empty */) {
      int current = runes.elementAt(i);

      // we assume that everything that is not
      // in Extended-ASCII set is an emoji...
      final isEmoji = current > 255;
      final shouldBreak = isEmoji ? (x) => x <= 255 : (x) => x > 255;

      final chunk = <int>[];
      while (!shouldBreak(current)) {
        chunk.add(current);
        if (++i >= runes.length) break;
        current = runes.elementAt(i);
      }

      children.add(
        TextSpan(
          text: String.fromCharCodes(chunk),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: fontSize,
            color: color,
            fontFamily: isEmoji ? 'Joypixels' : null,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return TextSpan(children: children);
  }
}
```

4. You can now use TextWithEmojis whenever you need :

```
    TextWithEmojis(
          text: "Hello  ",
          fontSize: 12,
          color: Colors.white
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Hot reloading or Hot [restaring](https://www.socheko.com) won't make the Text go to the incorrect state. Only running the app again.

Comment: that was not the question:) I was asking how to set the emoji font